# "java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "www.google.fr:80" "connect,resolve")"

Tags: java, javascript, applet

With my Java applet I run a HTTP request to www.google.fr but the browser displays:
"java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (" java.net.SocketPermission "" www.google.fr:80 "" connect, resolve ")"

I signed my applet with :

```
keytool -genkey -alias keyName
keytool -selfcert -alias keyName
jarsigner appletName.jar keyName
```

Sometimes I authorize the applet to execute.
But sometimes no pop-up appears with permission.

I load the applet with :

```
function loadApplet() {
    console.log('loadApplet [start]');
    $('#applet').html('<applet name="requestApplet" archive="applet.jar" code="GoogleRequest.class" height="10" width="10"></applet>');
    console.log(document.requestApplet.methodOfApplet()); // <-- Exception
    console.log('loadApplet [finish]');
}
```

Comment: can you share the code for the class you are using (where its making the connection)? Are you able to connect to any external service using that class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What JRE do you have ? I remember some 1.6 version (.22 if I remember right) had a "security upgrade" regarding networking and after that this kind of oddities started to occur.

Reason for this is that those Applet functions that are public to your javascript cannot call directly network functionalities of JRE. You have to decouple somehow Javascript from your network calls inside applet.

I implemented this with a kind of "message bus". Javascript calls Applet public function which puts "message" to internal bus, where another applet theread reads it and makes network call. It worked.

Comment: Try `AccessController.doPrivileged(..)` instead of the bus.